# Как реализовать редактируемый текст wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

К примеру, есть в блоке абзац с текстом.
Какие функцию существуют чтобы с админки передать измененный текст в тег?

Comment: В каком "блоке" есть? В какой-такой "тег"?

Comment: @SeVlad я не знаю, как вам объяснять что такое блок и тег, погуглите. На вопрос уже ответили

Comment: @StepanIvanov А, так это ж телепаты. Они у нас отвечают на любой, даже плохо сформулированный вопрос. Продолжайте и дальше клеймить этих недоучек, которые не понимают то, что вы имели ввиду и имеют наглость просить уточнить вопрос. </ирония>

Comment: @AK в вопросе всё понятно. Отличный развернутый ответ ниже уже дали, что ещё нужно-то. А иронизировать тут совсем не к месту

Comment: @StepanIvanov Я вам могу без всякой иронии сказать, что наличие ответа не гарантирует, что вопрос сформулирован понятно. На сайте полно вопросов плохо сформулированных, когда только перебором пяти-шести отвечающих попадают в ответ, который устроит спрашивающего. Поэтому просьбы уточнить непонятный вопрос - это хорошо и отвечать "объяснять подробнее я не хочу" - это не самая конструктивная позиция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Customizer](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/) (Пример реализации: [Как добавить редактируемый из админ-панели текст в подвал сайта в WordPress](https://compnot.ru/wordpress/kak-dobavit-redaktiruemyiy-iz-admin-paneli-tekst-v-podval-sayta-v-wordpress/)).
2. [Произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) и всяческие плагины для них, например, [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).
3. [Виджеты](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/).

Comment: 'priority' => 1, //с помощью этого параметра можно регулировать положение вкладки в списке вкладок

А как сделать чтобы priority был последним?

Comment: @StepanIvanov попробуйте указать число побольше, например, 'priority' => 999 .